# Spectrum of semi-infinite Toeplitz matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, toeplitz-matrices, infinite-matrices

I am considering a *self-adjoint semi-infinite Toeplitz matrix*, by which I mean
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_0  & a_1  & a_2  &  a_3 & \cdots \\
a_1^*& a_0  & a_1  &  a_2 & \ddots \\
a_2^* & a_1^*& a_0  & a_1  &  \ddots \\
a_3^*& a_2^* & a_1^*& a_0  & \ddots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{array}\right) $$
where $\{a_n\}_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}$ are complex numbers, and the star "$^*$" indicates the complex conjugation. It is assumed that $\sum_n \left|a_n\right|$ is finite.

I would like to understand the eigenvalue spectrum of $M$, especially when compared to its *infinite* analog $M_0$. It is well known (and shown e.g. by going to a Fourier-transformed basis) that the eigenvalues of
$$M_0 = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
\ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots  &  \ddots & \ddots \\
\ddots & a_0  & a_1  & a_2  &  a_3 & \ddots \\
\ddots & a_1^*& a_0  & a_1  &  a_2 & \ddots \\
\ddots & a_2^* & a_1^*& a_0  & a_1  &  \ddots \\
\ddots & a_3^*& a_2^* & a_1^*& a_0  & \ddots \\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{array}\right) $$
form a one-dimensional family
$$\lambda(\omega) = a_0 + 2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left[\Re[a_n] \cos(n \omega)+\Im[a_n] \sin(n \omega )\right]$$
where $\omega\in [0,2\pi)$. It then follows from the finiteness of $\sum_n |a_n|$ that the spectrum of $M_0$ is both compact and connected, namely an interval $$\textrm{spec}(M_0) = [x_1,x_2]$$ where $|x_{1,2}|<\infty$ are some finite numbers.

However, the spectrum of the *semi-infinite* matrix $M$ cannot be found using the same Fourier-transform trick, and I suspect there is no exact solution in this case.

**The question:** Is it true that $\textrm{spec}(M)\subseteq \textrm{spec}(M_0)$?

My simple numerical tests suggest that this should be true, but I didn't manage to prove this and I also failed to find a suitable reference. I was hoping that someone in the Stack Exchange community either readily knows the answer, or could point me to the relevant references/books.

If the answer turns out to be "no", then I also have a **second question:** Is $\textrm{spec}(M)$ always connected (as is the case for $M_0$), or is it possible that it exhibits some isolated eigenvalues detached from the continuum part of the spectrum?

Comment: Im interested in this: did you find an answer?

Comment: I found an answer to some closely related questions, which were sufficient for the physics application I had in mind. However, I don't feel too comfortable with matrix calculus and Lebesgue measure to confidently type the whole math answer. In the next two comments I briefly describe some results of two math papers that I found relevant -- if you have the time and interest, I would welcome if you mold them into a complete answer to my question above.

Comment: (1) For Toeplitz matrices (where $a_i$ are numbers), the work https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479896313036 describes several potential correspondences between finite $N\times N$ circular and Toeplitz matrices [the ``\tilde{c}[k]'' definition on p.2977 corresponds to my physics application]. My question above concerns the limit $N\to\infty$. Theorem 2 in Eq.(3) implies that the spectra of the two matrices in the limit $N\to\infty$ coincide, and that the corresponding Toeplitz matrix cannot have isolated eigenvalues detached from the continuum part of the spectrum.

Comment: (2) For block Toeplitz matrices (where $a_i$ are replaced by square matrices, and $^*$ by Hermitian conjugate), a related analysis is made in work https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479896313036. Theorem 3.1 on p.871 implies that the spectrum of a Toeplitz matrix is bounded by the infimum and supremum of the spectrum of the corresponding circular matrix for any finite size $N$ (i.e., not just the limit $N\to\infty$). This disallows isolated eigenvalues outside the [inf,sup] range. In contrast, discrete eigenvalues of the Toeplitz matrix within the "inner gaps" of the circulant spectrum are allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a good overview of the math literature to provide the original citable source for these spectral theorems.